# Apache reverse proxy and load balancer - does not work as it should

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I have 3 machines.
One (loadbalance.lan) is used as a load balancer, the other two (172.16.30.5 and 172.16.30.6) are tomcat's servers. Main page of the tomcat is listening on port 8080

Im typing in the browser loadbalance.lan/tomcat and I am able to see one of the tomcat content (default tomcat page)
The problem is page isn't displayed correctly. There's no images and when I click on any link it displays 404 Not found error.
Lets say I want to access one of the sub pages on the tomcat website. Tomcat website address: 172.16.30.5:8080
Now I can choose, lets say "status" link which redirects me to: 172.16.30.5:8080/manager/status (and works fine)

When I access the same page but via reverse proxy server (loadbalance.net) and click that link on the loadbalance.lan page, links redirect me to loadbalance.lan/manager/status and I get 404 error.
Of course when I type in the browser  loadbalance.lan/tomcat/manager/status it displays correct.

Problem with the images is also weird. When I use url: loadbalance.lan/tomcat I can't see images (Tomcat logo)
When I use this one: loadbalance.lan/tomcat/ (slash at the end) it's ok. At least images because links still redirect in wrong place.

Here is my loadbalance.lan apache config:

```
   <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   <VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyRequests     Off
    ProxyVia          On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy balancer://cluster>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Proxy balancer://cluster>
    BalancerMember http://172.16.30.5:8080
    BalancerMember http://172.16.30.6:8080
    <Proxy balancer://cluster>
    </Proxy>

    <Location /tomcat>
    ProxyPass balancer://cluster
    ProxyPassReverse balancer://cluster
    </Location>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Could someone help me with this?
Obviously there is something wrong with that proxy but I have no idea how to fix that :(

Answer (score 2):

From [ProxyPassReverse](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) documentation (strong added):

> This directive lets Apache adjust the URL in the **Location**, **Content-Location** and **URI headers** on HTTP redirect responses. This is essential when Apache is used as a reverse proxy (or gateway) to avoid by-passing the reverse proxy because of HTTP redirects on the backend servers which stay behind the reverse proxy.
>
> Only the HTTP response headers specifically mentioned above will be rewritten. **Apache will not rewrite other response headers, nor will it rewrite URL references inside HTML pages**. This means that if the proxied content contains absolute URL references, they will by-pass the proxy. A third-party module that will look inside the HTML and rewrite URL references is Nick Kew's **mod_proxy_html**.

So, **the proxy job is not to rewrite the html content of the pages**, if the proxyied content does not know that the final url should contain `/tomcat` extension and the proxy does not alter the pages... you're stuck.

This is usually something you do not see because the `172.16.30.5:8080` part is well rewritten in `localhost.lan`, but this rewrite is not made by the proxy, quite certainly because urls are in fact only relative (`<img src="/foo/bar.png">`). Check the source code of the page to see if the domain name is really rewritten in urls).

There's several ways of handling that:
 - You could avoid altering relative urls paths in, the proxy (so not using a `tomcat/` prefix, but instead a dedicated virtualhost with a name, like `tomcat.lodabalncer.lan`). 
 - You could also use some dedicated tools, like [mod_proxy_html](http://apache.webthing.com/mod_proxy_html/) to rewrite the content of the pages, but that's a slow and complex thing.
 - The third way is to manage the final full url on the application side (here tomcat) and detect the proxy chain elements in X-Forwareded-for Header to rebuild the right domain.
 - Some applications provides tools for that, like the [VirtualHostMonster](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/VirtualHosting.html) in Zope

For tomcat the preferred tool is `mod_proxy_ajp` and not `mod_proxy`. But for a load balancer proxy I do not think you can use `mod_proxy_ajp`. And, it's been a long time since I made this, but in my memory I think `mod_jk` was the solution to that.

Read this [full documentation on tomcat proxying](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html) for details. At least you should get some hints for the solution.